# Problem shutdown Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, shutdown, 17.10

I'm new with Ubuntu and in this forum.

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10. But I have some problems with shutdown. The process (shutdown or reboot) requires tens of minutes and the screen is like the picture attached.

That problem happen only if i'm connected to wifi, infact it doesn't happen if my laptop is connected via ethernet and the shutdown process is, in this case, very fast.

Furthermore if i'm connected via Wi-Fi, after 10/15 min the connection is interrupted and I can't open settings (both from terminal and from desktop icon).

Asus - F556U

thank you for your help.

[Example of screen during shutdown process.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFfer.jpg)

Comment: This appears to be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/970355/ubuntu-17-10-takes-very-long-time-to-shut-down

Comment: I have the same issue. What is your computer brand?